# Assigning the fulfillment group based on user's location using assignment lookup rules in catalog task advance script

Tags: servicenow

I created a script in catalog task in workflow to find the location of the current user and find which assignment lookup rule should be use base on the location.
But it's not working.

```
var userlocation = gs.getUser().getRecord().getDisplayValue("location");

var target = new GlideRecord('dl_u_assignment');
target.addQuery('location', userlocation);
target.addEncodedQuery('category=inquiry^subcategory=email');
target.query();

while(target.next()) {  
    var assignment_group = target.assignment_group; 
    task.task_fulfillment_group.setDisplayValue(assignment_group);
}
```

Appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the table name that looks like a data lookup table. Is there any reason why you are not trying to implement this requirement using the [Data Lookup Definitions](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/madrid-platform-administration/page/administer/field-administration/reference/r_CreateCustomDataLookups.html) rather than Assignment Rules?

If you are insistent on taking this route, then the last line should read

```
current.task_fulfillment_group.setValue(assignment_group);
```

as that would be a Sys ID and not the display value of the location. The script would be running on the current task record, so it's accessed using `current`. Also, take steps to verify that the field name is indeed *task_fulfillment_group*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the given answer, please add the following at the last line of your code, **provided** that task is also a GlideRecord.

```
task.setValue("task_fulfillment_group", assignment_group);
task.update();
```